# Generate zip code based on City and State with Google API

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, google-maps, geocode

Would there be a way to do a zip code lookup based on City/State input in a form?  I'm thinking the Google geocode API might be the right direction.  Any thoughts?  I have a site built on Wordpress so the code would have to utilize PHP.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Which* zip code? Almost every city in the US contains multiple zip codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YQL can do things like this:

```
select  name from geo.places.children where parent_woeid in (select woeid from geo.places where text="sunnyvale, usa" limit 1) AND placetype = 11
```

returns:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 6,
  "created": "2011-03-16T06:49:09Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "place": [
    {
     "name": "94086"
    },
    {
     "name": "94087"
    },
    {
     "name": "94088"
    },
    {
     "name": "94089"
    },
    {
     "name": "94090"
    },
    {
     "name": "94085"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

[YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%20name%20from%20geo.places.children%20where%20parent_woeid%20in%20%28select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22sunnyvale,%20usa%22%20limit%201%29%20AND%20placetype%20=%2011)

There are examples on there on how to implement queries like this in both [PHP](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_php) and [Javascript](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_javascript) on their site.

Answer (score 1):

Geocoding is where you find the coordinates of an address. Yes you could geocode a city,state but this would give you he center of the city (as defined by the geocoder's internal database - typically a centroid or 'city hall'.

Most cities have multiple zip codes: Do you want all of these?
Similarly a zip code could contain multiple cities - especially in rural areas where zip codes can be large and cities are what other countries would call 'villages' and 'hamlets'

So you best bet is probably to get a database. There might be some free ones around (Geonames comes to mind but I don't think it has zip codes), but you might end up having to buy one.

Answer (score 0):

First a note on the Google API: be aware of [Google's TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) so you don't take a wasted path as others have done (sometimes unknowingly). Specifically: "Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.".

Your best bet is to get a [free zip code database](http://greatdata.com/free-zip-code-database) if your project is not mission-critical; otherwise, you'll probably need a good commercial-grade database. Just google "commercial grade zip code database".

Also, see a good [stack-overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428889/lookup-county-name-using-address-city-state-and-zip/11140033#11140033) about this topic.